# Accessing properties of a function inside different levels of its "prototype" functions -- and -- recursive functions

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, prototype

Ok, this has been confusing me for days! Let's say I have something like:

```
var FooBar = function(args) {
   this.annoy = typeof args == "boolean" ? args : false;
   this.Foo();
}

FooBar.prototype.Foo = function() {
   if (this.annoy)
      window.alert("My name is Foo!")
   else
      window.console.log("My name is Foo!")
   this.Bar()
}

FooBar.prototype.Bar = function() {
   if (this.annoy)
      window.alert("My name is Bar!")
   else
      window.console.log("My name is Bar!")
}
```

This works fine. However, what if `Bar()` was defined as a property of another object which is further a property of `FooBar`'s `prototype`, is there a way to access `annoy` in the new `Bar()` without having to pass `annoy` as an argument to it? For example:

```
FooBar.prototype.evenDeeper = {
   Bar: function() {
      // I wish to access "annoy" here!
   },

   anotherOne: function() {
   },

   yetAnotherOne: 'value'
}
```

I might be wrong but I am sure that inside `Foo()`, `Bar()` would be referred to as `this.evenDeeper.Bar()`, wouldn't it? Moreover, what if `Bar()` wanted to be recursive? Would `Bar()` just refer to itself as `Bar()` inside itself, or as `Foobar.evenDeeper.Bar()` or `this.Bar()` or what?

## Summary

1. How can `Bar()` access `annoy` if it's inside `evenDeeper`?
2. How does `Bar()` refer to itself within itself?

---

Disclaimer: I am **not** even remotely planning on annoying anyone with `alert()`s! ;)

Comment: When you do `this.evenDeeper.Bar()`, the value of `this` in the `Bar()` method will be the `evenDeeper` object. At this level, `Bar()` has no access to the `.annoy` property of the original object. Remember that your `evenDeeper` object is shared because it's on the `.prototype` of the constructor. If `Bar()` was to add a property to that object, all other objects created from the constructor would see that property.

Comment: No I mean *inside* the function `Foo()`, if I want to call `Bar()`, I would, instead of using `this.Bar()` as in the original code, use `this.evenDeeper.Bar()` wouldn't I? Because inside `Foo()` the value of `this` is the prototype, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, read the first sentence of my comment above. My point is that for your recursive call as you asked about in the sentence starting with *"Morover..."*, you no longer have access to the original object that has the `.annoy` property. It's pretty unusual to have a plain object on the `.prototype` of a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
A) pass a variable to evenDeeper.Bar;
B) use evenDeeper.bar.apply(new FooBar(args)) to access FooBar prototype using 'this';
C) assign evenDeeper.annoy the FooBar.annoy variable (not recommended because booleans are passed by value and it won't reflect changes to it)

2.
A) use this.Bar() from within evenDeeper.Bar() and it should refer to itself unless you have changed the 'this' variable.
B) pass this.Bar as a callback to this.Bar() and execute it within itself
C) declare this.Bar() in a function context so it can refer to itself as simply Bar(), example follows:

```
FooBar.prototype.evenDeeper = (function () {
    function Bar() {
        if (this.annoy) {
            alert('are you annoyed yet?');
        }
        Bar.apply(this);
    }
    return {
        Bar: Bar,
        anotherOne: function () {},
        yetAnotherOne: function () {}
    };
}());

var test = new FooBar(true);
// WARNING: this will never finish!
test.evenDeeper.Bar.apply(test);
```

This is a generic solution, if you posted something more specific there are most likely better ways to achieve what you want. Personally, I would avoid creating a function which relies on a namespace other than the one it is in.

Comment: Your comments are most appreciated. **1(A)-** That is the best way, in my opinion. It's fairly simple, though it lacks the elegance I was looking for.  **1(B)-** Forgive my ignorance, but I didn't know about `.apply()`. I looked it up and am still trying to comprehend what it does. Without knowing what it exactly does, I might end up creating another whirlpool in my code. **1(C)** Agreed, it's inappropriate although in this particular instance it isn't a problem. Nonetheless, in my code, `evenDeeper` is named `methods`. It's stupid for `methods` to contain anything but methods.

Comment: Continuing: **2(A)** is exactly what I was looking for. **2(B)-** That's a neat trick! Can be useful when I need to let the caller decide if the function should recur or call another function instead. Quite intelligent, nonetheless! **2(C)-** Again, `.apply()` and I think it's an overkill. 2(A) does the job quite fine. Thank you for your reply. It made me slightly wiser. ;)